# Awk: how to compare two strings in one line

Tags: bash, awk

I have a dataset with 20 000 probes, they are in two columns, 21nts each. From this file I need to extract the lines in which last nucleotide in Probe1 column matches last nucleotide in in Probe 2 column. So far I tried AWK (substr) function, but didn't get the expected outcome. Here is one-liner I tried:

```
awk '{if (substr($2,21,1)==substr($4,21,1)){print $0}}'
```

Another option would be to anchor last character in columns 2 and 4 (`awk '$2~/[A-Z]$/`), but I can't find a way to match the probes in two columns using regex. All suggestions and comments will be very much appreciated.

Example of dataset:

```
        Probe 1                     Probe 2
4736    GGAGGAAGAGGAGGCGGAGGA   A   GGAGGACGAGGAGGAGGAGGA
4737    GGAGGAAGAGGAGGGAGAGGG   B   GGAGGACGAGGAGGAGGAGGG
4738    GGAGGATTTGGCCGGAGAGGC   C   GGAGGAGGAGGAGGACGAGGT
4739    GGAGGAAGAGGAGGGGGAGGT   D   GGAGGACGAGGAGGAGGAGGC
4740    GGAGGAAGAGGAGGGGGAGGC   E   GGAGGAGGAGGACGAGGAGGC
```

Desired output:

```
4736    GGAGGAAGAGGAGGCGGAGGA   A   GGAGGACGAGGAGGAGGAGGA
4737    GGAGGAAGAGGAGGGAGAGGG   B   GGAGGACGAGGAGGAGGAGGG
4740    GGAGGAAGAGGAGGGGGAGGC   E   GGAGGAGGAGGACGAGGAGGC
```

Comment: The `awk` example you gave already produces the desired output that you described. What more do you need?

Comment: It works indeed, sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will filter the input, matching lines where the last character of the 2nd column is equal to the last character of the 4th column:

```
awk 'substr($2, length($2), 1) == substr($4, length($4), 1)'
```

What I changed compared to your sample script:

- Move the `if` statement out of the `{ ... }` block into a filter
- Use `length($2)` and `length($4)` instead of hardcoding the value 21
- The `{ print $0 }` is not needed, as that is the default action for the matched lines